# Ajax php handler file only works when in the plugin main file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is a general "why" and "how" question to the confusion around the Ajax handling. I have finally started to get somewhere for implementing my first complete Ajax posting form. I struggled for such a long time with all the various demos in different directions on different sites. The biggest problem has been that the only way I get a response from my php handler, back into the form was by having the php in the base file of the plugin, and not in a separate file.

My simple test works fine with all the php in one file, the form in another file, and a separate js file. I can not have the php handler out from the main install plugin file it seems.  Why and how can I move the handler out of this base file. I have played around, but cannot find any definite answers to being able to do this.

Any advice or help greatly appreciated. Thanks. -- I have now added the code which I used as a test to try and see what was going wrong. This works when the_action_function() is in the base file to the plugin, but not when loaded in another file location. How can I move it another file?

```
function pob_noted_testplugin(){

 wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .          '/includes/1ext/js/pob_noted_form_script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

 }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' ); 




function the_action_function(){

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 echo"Note added:" . " " . $name;  

 wp_die();
 }
```

the .js script

```
function submit_me(){
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, 

      jQuery("#theForm").serialize(),

        function(response_from_the_action_function){
          jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
        }

    );
    $("#theForm")[0].reset();

  });
}
```

the form

```
function hello_world_ajax_frontend(){
 $the_form = '
 <form id="theForm">
 <input id="name" name="name" value = "" type="text" />
 <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook" /> 
 <input id="submit_button" value = "Click This" type="button" onClick="submit_me();" />
 </form>
 <div id="response_area">
   Response
 </div>';
 return $the_form;
 }
  add_shortcode("hw_ajax_frontend", "hello_world_ajax_frontend");
 ?>
```

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: added, sorry, should have thought more about my question.